# Bash extract last n characters, compare to separate column

Tags: string, bash, awk, extract

I have an input file which contains the following columns:

```
'-'    CT    C>CCT  
'-'    TA    G>GTA  
'-'    TAT    A>ATAT
```

Basically, I am trying to test whether the final n characters after the arrow in column 3 are the same as the contents of column 2, where n is the difference in length between the letters before and after the arrow.

It seems that everything I've tried so far has thrown an error. I'm thinking along the following lines:

```
awk -F"\t" '{split($3,x,">");
{n_base=length(x[2])-length(x[1]);
ins={$x[2]: -$n_base};
if($2 == $ins) {print $0}}'
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ins={$x[2]: -$n_base}` is a shell language construct. awk is not shell, awk is a tool you can call from shell just like `cut`, `grep`, etc. Also, you get the value of an awk variable by naming the variable, just like in C, not by sticking a `$` in front of it like you do in shell. Get the book `Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition` by Arnold Robbins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't show any sample output so this is a guess but it SOUNDS like all you want is:

```
$ awk -F'[\t>]' '$2==substr($4,length($3)+1)' file
'-'     CT      C>CCT
'-'     TA      G>GTA
'-'     TAT     A>ATAT
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you want:

```
awk -F'\t' '
        {
          split($3, parts, ">");
          fl = length(parts[2])
          check = substr(parts[2], fl-length($2)+1)
        }

        $2 == check {print}
        '
```

Comment: The third arg for split is an RE. By not using RE delimiters '/.../' you are telling awk that your RE is inside a string which will cause it to be parsed twice, once when the script is read and then again when it is executed. That won't matter for the single char you have now, but for other separators will cause you a lot of pain having to double-escape RE metacharacters. Just use RE delimiters unless you have a very specific reason not to (e.g. concatenating a string literal with a variable): `split($3,parts,/>/)`.

Comment: Also, lose the spurious trailing semi-colon and you don't need `{print}` after your final condition as that's the default action.